# Trying to read from pipe to a String but it doesnt read the entire String

Tags: c, malloc, pipe, fork

I'm using a child process to execute the sha1sum program. For some context, basically sha1sum will take a file and create a unique code for it. (Doesn't do exactly this but that's not really important).
The code is 40 chars long.

So, my child process will execute it, and the parent process will save the code and put it in a buffer.
I built a main function to test if it was doing what i wanted and i noticed the String wasn't complete. I'm thinking its a malloc problem. I commented on the code why i think that.

```
char* getN(char *name){
int fd[2],pid;
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(41*sizeof(char));

pipe(fd);
pid=fork();

if(!pid){
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    close(fd[1]);
    execlp("sha1sum","sha1sum",name,NULL);
}
else{
    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer)); /* if i change this sizeof to like sizeof(buffer)+2 it prints 2 more chars than it previously did. no clue why. */
    close(fd[0]);
    wait(NULL);
}
return buffer;
}



int main(){
    char *a=getN("file.pdf"); // file that's in my current directory.
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check what the size of `buffer` actually is, as in a `printf` statement with `sizeof(buffer)`?

Comment: try reading the characters one by one with a loop instead or reading all at once it may work.

Answer (score 1):

buffer is a pointer, not a static array, so sizeof(buffer) returns the size of a pointer. (4 on 32-bit architecture, 8 on 64-bit). When you call read, you don't want the size of the pointer, you want the size of the data that it is pointing to, so you need to pass in the same value you passed as an argument to malloc (in this case, 41).

Comment: I assumed it would be a problem with the sizeof so that's the 1st thing that i tried. The problem with that is it gives me a weird result. it's returning this: 2ff7d93c1f79afd6a0f63c90f1ca2bbbc0645995 \O??
instead of 2ff7d93c1f79afd6a0f63c90f1ca2bbbc0645995

Comment: `read()` doesn't add a null terminator, you need to add that to the end of the data. `read()` returns the number of bytes read, add the null after that byte.

Comment: @ohiohai You also need to call `read()` in a loop until you get EOF. There's no guarantee that a single call will return everything.

Comment: Nvm, i figured it out. It wasn't printing right because after those 40 chars sha1sum also prints the name of the file. All i had to do was force the buffer[40] to be a '\0'. I'm an idiot.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.